# append search term to a log file name

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts

I wrote a script (`fetch.sh`) to search for terms in PDF files (old digitized OCR'd newspapers) using `PDFGREP`. It works great. It prompts the user for the search term (`foo`) and file to search (`year.pdf`).

I want to capture the output to a log while still displaying the results on screen. I successfully used `| tee log` to do this 3 ways

1. from prompt: `fetch.sh | tee log`
2. from prompt: `fetch.sh | tee log.foo`
3. inside the script I can do:

   ```
   (
      fetch.sh
   ) | tee log
   ```

What I really want is to do it as part of `fetch.sh` but to be of the format `log.foo` (file format of 2. but executed as 3).

Inside `fetch.sh` I have tried:

- `) | tee log.$foo` ... yields file named `log.`
- `) | tee log."$foo"` ... yields file named `log.`
- `) | tee log.'$foo'` ... yields `log.$foo` (literal, no substitution for `$foo`)
- `) | tee log.${foo}` ... yields file named `log.`
- `) | tee log."${foo}" ... yields file named`log.`
- `) | tee log.'${foo}'` ... yields `log.${foo}` (literal, no substitution for `$foo`)

In all cases the output is correctly captured but the file name is never what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set foo as a variable inside fetch.sh?

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you're having is that by using `( ... )`, you're running all of the commands in a sub-shell of the current process. As this subshell is a child process, no variables that you've assigned will be passed to the parent (your main script). This means that variable never reaches your `tee` command.

The solution is fairly simple, within your script you must assign the variable before you start the brackets, this variable will then be available to the `tee` command.

For example, if the file extension you wanted to add is `.txt`:

```
foo=txt
(
commands from fetch.sh
) | tee log."$foo"
```

Note that I've used double quotes, which the shell will expand, to make sure that, in the unlikely event that your extension contains spaces, it is still intact after expansion.

If you need to set `foo` from within fetch.sh, you will need to use another method of grouping your script's commands.

Comment: thank you ... I understand. I tried some variations of where the "(" was placed [i.e., after user input is read] and that did not work but not a crisis. I was only trying to clean things up for someone else who is not used to working at $.